# Tor install on CentOS server

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, tor

I have followed the instructions provided here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en
However, when running yum install tor, i get the following dependency error:

```
Error: Package: tor-0.2.5.10-tor.2.rh7_0_1406.x86_64 (tor)
           Requires: libevent-2.0.so.5()(64bit)
```

I then proceed to installing libevent. For some reason, i do not get the right version from yum, so i have to download the libevent library from http://libevent.org/ and run the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/libevent
make
make install
```

When i try to run `yum install tor` i still get the same dependency error. How can i tell yum where i have installed libevent? Or what's the issue here?

Comment: Could yum localinstall be what i am searching for here?

Comment: I am having same problem and the only answer is not relevant to me

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install it through yum. You can just download it from here:
 [tor browser for linux](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux)

and then you just do:

```
tar xf tor-browser-linux64-*.tar.xz
```

After that you can just move it to /opt/tor-browser_en-US by:

```
sudo mv tor-browser_en-US /opt/tor-browser_en-US
```

Also, if you want to create a menu item for it, you can do:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop
```

and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser
Exec=/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
Terminal=false
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser is +1 for privacy and -1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

and save and close by:

```
Ctrl + O
Ctrl + X
```